# Reset query when changing the product per page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

I created a dropdown product per page list. It works fine but the problem is when I go to the latest product page and then change the product per page dropdown to something larger (for example from 50 to 100) it redirects to 404 pages which makes sense since we don't have such this page. here is the scenario:

1. Consider we're in this page: https://www.mywebsite.com/products (Number of products per page is 50)
2. I go to latest page from pagination: https://www.mywebsite.com/products/page/3/ (Number of products per page is still 50)
3. Then I change the product per page dropdown number to 100 products per page.
4. It redirects to https://www.mywebsite.com/products/page/3/?perpage=100 (404 Not found)

Whereas it should redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com/products/?perpage=100 which is a correct query.
In other words, it should reset the query of pagination before changing the number of products per page.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'pro_selectbox', 25 );
function pro_selectbox() {
$per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo '<div class="woocommerce-perpage">';
echo '<span>Puppies per page: <select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';
$orderby_options = array(
'50' => '50',
'100' => '100'
);
foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pro_pre_get_products_query' );
function pro_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
$per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
}
}
```

The question is how can I change the query from this: https://www.mywebsite.com/products/page/3/?perpage=100 to this: https://www.mywebsite.com/products/?perpage=100 by modifying the above snippet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/180514

Comment: Thanks @Dlk, I don't know how should I seperate the perpage loop from main loop. I think it should be in the same loop. I set '$query->set('paged',1);' before '$query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page )' and it solved but the pagination doesn't work anymore